# CSS background-image bottom of div

Tags: css, html, overflow, background-image

Here's what I have:

```
<div id="page_container">
    A short text
</div>

#page_container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 280px;
    right: 30px;
    background-color: #D0D0CD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
    height: 1060px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-image: url(./library/grappe.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
```

So, my div is 1060px, on the right of my screen, and has an image on the right bottom corner. So far so right. Nice looking with a short text.

Due to the overflow: auto, a long text won't make my div higher, but add a scrollbar to it, that's what I want.

However, the background-image stays glued to the div right bottom corner, instead of basically not showing and first show when I scroll down the div that has a scrollbar. Basically the image stays on the same position, like a `position: fixed`. Can't get to change that behavior.

Comment: make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: when I scroll, the image does stay the same. What do you want the image to do when you scroll?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add an inner div, and that inner div will have the background while the first one will handle the scrolling.

```
<div id="page_container">
    <div class="block_container">
        A short text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS part

```
#page_container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 280px;
    right: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
    height: 1060px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#page_container .block_container
{
    background: #D0D0CD url('./library/grappe.png') bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Probably should add `min-height: 100%` to `.block_container` to ensure that the background image is always at the bottom.
*Edit: I cannot type today*

Comment: thanks for your answer. I thought about it, tried it, and just tried it again with your exact solution. But the image isn't displayed anymore...

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work without having to have another div there.

```
#page_container {
  background: url('IMAGE_URL') no-repeat bottom right, linear-gradient(315deg, #0F3052 0%, #11A0B0 100%);
  background-size: contain;
}
```